How do native English speakers know the archaic or domain/time specific words in English literature like "The Tale of Two Cities“?
I have been reading The Tale of Two Cities for multiple months. The progress is pretty slow because I would like to know most of the details in a way that I can learn some literature techniques in English by Charles Dickens. However, I'm wondering how native English speakers know the archaic or domain specific words in novels like this.
For example, I would like to know how much you understand the meaning of these (50) words:
Arrear,  asseveration, asunder, balustrade, beckon, brawny, breech,  cachet, canter, compunction, consignment, coppice, curtsey, demur, fain, filament, flambeau, frill, gainsay, gossamer, jalousie, lacquey, lee-dyed, malady,  mahogany, meekness, menagerie, myriad, paunch, peal, pilferer, piscatorial, pith, provender, purloiner,   quaint, rickety, scullery, scruple,  staid, stench, swoon, tattered, teem, throng, tidings, tiller, trenchant, upholsterer, and wolfishly.
Usually, these words have Germanic/Viking/Anglo-Saxon origin thus it's quite difficult for me to encounter similar words or pre/suffix roots to infer their meanings.
I'm also curious, as a native speaker, may you share some personal experience/stories (maybe in childhood) on how you knew some of the words above in real life, or maybe you actually need certain aids while reading novels by 19th century authors like Charles Dickens.

I am a native AmE speaker, and come from a highly educated family. I know and could define most of these words without looking them up. (A quick glance over your list is that I know 38 of the 50 listed.) I could guess at the meaning of a few of the others, but wouldn't be sure. The ones I don't know wouldn't impact my ability to read a book that contained them most of the time.

Typically, people who are native English speakers learn words like this in a few ways. Children have a class in school called Spelling which teaches explicitly both how to spell words and what they mean. Words like these might be explicitly taught to high schooler aged students (ages 13-18). But beyond that, the English language has so many words that using context clues to understand a word you have never seen before is a skill taught in school as well. I am sure that I learned most of these just by reading them in books.

Some of these are also more common than others. Every native English speaker knows what a curtsey is. Many English speakers would not know balustrade or purloiner. So there is a range.

Reminds me of a story only last night. A friend told me about an incident at her local pre-school. Two kids were fighting and she said, "Quarrelsome, aren't they!" She's in her 60s and the two other staff were in their 20s. They both looked at her blankly: "What is this word, quarrelsome?" She was so relieved to find out that at least I understood!

Thank you for a half dozen new words to add to my collection. You fool, my power only grows…

And contrary to what you write, a fair number of the words in your list have romanic  (French) roots, not nordic/germanic.

They're not all archaic. Canter is one of the ways a horse runs, mahogany is a type of wood, wolfish simply means 'like a wolf', women's dresses etc. may be decorated with frills...

See also this question.

@KateBunting that’s why I said “or domain specific” words, like in the ontology of animals, dresses, etc.

OK - but I would never have thought of frill as an obscure or difficult word.

It's all about reading. For example: Edgar Allen Poe wrote: The Purloined Letter, so ever since I read that I've known that word [40 years?]. As for the others, I just know them also from reading but don't know specifically when I learned them or saw them for the first time. The only one I have never seen is: lee-dyed. But I assume it means dyed in the lees of the wine. If you read magazines like The New Yorker or The Atlantic Monthly or the BrE: Times Literary Supplement, you'll see a wide range of words...

Just recently I learned one of my nephews didn't know wan or doddery. Why? He simply does not read novels or literary-type writing.

@KateBunting "frill" is extremely difficult to me if I never saw or paid attention to it, especially: these germanic/dutch origin English words with about 4 - 7 characters use RANDOM flow of consonants to construct the word, it would be very difficult for me to infer the meaning from prefix or suffix. For example, consider how many words have the structure "*aunch"? https://wordnik.com/lists/words-with-aunch-in-them that's a pain for a non-native speakers to learn these words, especially you already know some of them, learning a new one would easily make you mess it up with all others.

aunch? That is not a prefix or suffix or root or stem.

I;ve voted to close.  There isn't "an answer" to this question, there are 500 million different answer.  Everyone is different, everyone has their own answer.  But as noted, many of these words are not particularly archaic and are in normal use.

The vast majority of those words are not archaic at all, and are just every day words that most educated English speakers will be familiar with and learn by reading and studying English at school. Around half of them are from Latin/Romance roots. Only one of these words is obsolete: asservation. Also Flambeau is a French word, and not used often today for obvious reasons:  it's a flaming torch. The term lee-dyed is a bit obscure without context, but refers to the lees (the sediment) at the bottom of a wine container, and so the meaning is easily understood from context.

@JamesK I don't agree with you. There are definitely some or several common patterns of native speakers learn the words, especially in their education system. Refer to the "summer reading list" program mentioned in other commenters.
Also, why people are so sensitive to the "archaic"? I said "archaic OR domain specific words", if they are 10% archaic words and 90% domain specific words (frill, gossamer, tiller, lee-dyed, scullery, etc.. they are very domain specific for some aspects of regular life, aren't they?), my statement still holds true.

Most of the words in your list are not domain specific.  I can't see any words that are obviously from any particular jargon.  Some refer to things that are uncommon now, or are rather old fashioned.  But there is no "answer" to this question.  Some native speakers will know more of those words, some will know fewer, there's no answer to this question, everyone will be different.

@JamesK numerous people answered below did give the ANSWERS, there is no "STANDARD ANSWER" doesn't mean there's NO answer. what about a question "what's your favorite thing in your childhood"? is that a legitmate question? it is different to everyone too.  as for "domain specific", that is my definition, no matter you agree or not: for ex, "canter" describes the gait of a horse, "tiller" means nothing to me if I'm not a farmer, "tidings" explicitly marked by dic as ARCHAIC meaning of "news", "scullery" means a room not existed in any apart/houses I lived, why should I bother with these words?

That's exactly my point. "what's your favorite thing in your childhood?" is not a valid question for this forum because it is primarily opinion based.  In exactly the same way as your question is.  In my opinion "canter" is a fairly common word.  A tiller is someone who tills.  etc etc.  Whether you should bother with these words is a matter of opinion. It's up to you.  That's why this isn't an answerable question.  I'm not judging you. You've done nothing wrong, except that this isn't really answerable except with "I think that...."

@JamesK that's good know! does this forum have a preference on specific language points / words / grammar / behavior instead of general language studying experience? do you have a recommendation for another site for my question?

I’m voting to close this question because it should be on META or another site.

@Stephie Roots in a Romance language. [not romanic, I can only assume those upticks are from  speakers who don't know this]

@Lambie The comment was upvoted because it makes a correct point, which is not significantly hindered by one typo. (I'm guessing the intended word was Romantic, sense 3, but either way the meaning is clear.)

@DLosc No, the word is Romance, as in the Romance languages. romantic is not the adjective for that group of languages, the word Romance is. Also, we spell names and their adjectives with caps: the Nordic/Germanic languages.


I'm wondering how native English speakers know archaic or domain specific words...

First observation:
I don't know if this is necessarily true. For example, I knew about 45 of the 50 words in your list well enough to not have to look them up. And with the other 5, my guess is that I would instinctively know their meaning from context as I encountered them while reading A Tale of Two Cities.
But: This wouldn't be true of my wife, for at least two reasons. First, although she is a woman with marvellous life experience and common sense, she is not formally educated in areas that would strengthen her literary skills. She left school at 16, whereas I have three tertiary degrees. Second, we read very different kinds of literature. My reading range has included Dickens, but not hers.
Second observation:
This flows from the first point. No one knows everything. While I might have no problems with Dickens, I would likely have more doubtful words in Shakespeare, and when we get back to Chaucer, well... What can I say?
Also I have problems in the other direction. I'm old enough that understanding the language of Twitter and TikTok can be problematic. (I had to check the spelling of TikTok, because I couldn't remember if it was one word or two!) This is all just an example of language as a living thing, ebbing and flowing, changing with times and cultures.
So what do you do? I would simply encourage you to read. Read large passages. Read out loud. Read in silence. Read by yourself or with a partner. But focus on the reading, not the studying. If there are words you don't understand, that's ok. Make your best guess, and carry on reading. At the end of a chapter you might choose a couple of those "guesswork words" and check them in a dictionary to see how close you were. But if you're wrong, don't worry. You'll get better as you continue.
A fascinating example of this approach is seen in the story of C S Lewis, who tells in his autobiography Surprised by Joy how he learned Greek. His tutor simply read to him large sections of Homer, then translated the sections, then left Lewis to copy him! Lewis said of this approach:

The great gain was that I very soon became able to understand a great deal without (even mentally) translating it; I was beginning to think in Greek. That is the great Rubicon to cross in learning any language. Those in whom the Greek word lives only while they are hunting for it in the lexicon, and who then substitute the English word for it, are not reading the Greek at all; they are only solving a puzzle. The very formula, ‘Naus means a ship’, is wrong. Naus and ship both mean a thing, they do not mean one another. Behind Naus, as behind navis or naca, we want to have a picture of a dark, slender mass with sail or oars, climbing the ridges, with no officious English word intruding.

(You can see more of this story here.)

Must you bring your wife into it? Poor lady. Three tertiary degrees, indeed. I'm surprised you didn't know all the words.

It's not about putting my wife down. We've been happily married for over 35 years, and she's the most important person in the world to me. But she's also the clearest personal example I can think of that two people can both be native English speakers and yet have a quite different vocabulary, for any number of reasons. (As for the list, jalousie and lee-dyed were two that tripped me up.)

Many native speakers would not know a large number of those words when they encounter them for the first time, in high school or college.  They would have to consult a dictionary.  They are not archaic for the most part.
P.S. It is now and then possible to arrive at a meaning if the word has a recognizable morphology and one knows the meaning of the root. But English writing does not use ideographs, but an alphabet to represent sounds.

P.S. Not sure why this got a downvote since it states what I know to be fact.  For five years I taught freshman English classes at an Ivy League university (which tend to attract students who are very accomplished academically) and  many of them would have had to look up some of those words in a dictionary because they did not know their meanings or were unsure of them.

Any good high school English teacher might assign A Tale of Two Cities to their students. It's a favorite for many of them. Nowadays, it's no longer always called English but rather Language Arts.
In my case, it was in a list of assigned summer reading (novels) along with instructions to write down and look up words we readers (we were 12 years old) did not know.These summer reading lists were in play for me from 7th through 12th grade. In the US, most colleges ask for applicants to have taken the SATs (Scholastic Apptitude Test: Math and English), and in preparation for that they do vocabulary tests, formally or on their own. This pre-high school and high school period was probably when my vocabulary grew the most. And then, of course, the reading continued in college but often not just novels or plays but also history and politics or law for non-lawyers, for example.
In my case also, I went to private schools but I know from friends that good public schools also had these summer reading lists.
In high school English classes, there is also emphasis put on stems, roots, prefixes and suffixes of words and for that a lot of Greek and Latin is learned as English has many throwbacks to those dead languages. However, in the Tale of Two Cities list, that would not be so useful. It is useful in medicine, history, politics and other social and exact sciences.
Looking over that list, I have to say I knew all of them except lee-dyed, which without looking it up, I assme means dyed in the lees of some kind of wine. Maybe I'm wrong. :)
Today, kids no longer read books much or as much. Therefore, their vocabulary, as a general matter, is not as broad as that of previous generations, all things being equal.
So, to answer the question, I'd say: It's all in the reading you do. That's how native speakers learn the kinds of words you have in your variegated (both senses)  list of words. :)

Thanks for sharing! This is the first time I know the "summer reading list" program for kids and students.
Also, do you think there's a bias on this forum that native English speakers here have higher reading skills and larger vocabulary as they apparently paid more attention to language learning?

Very likely, since only people who love words and language would want to bother checking it regularly to see what questions they can answer.

@CynthiaZ Is that a real question? You asked how native speakers learn that list you posted. I have answered it. Native speakers learn their respective languages differently than foreign language speakers. How did you learn your native language?

@Lambie yes, let me rephrase the extra question: do we have a bias that native English speakers here (who paid more attention to language learning apparently) OVER OTHER average native English speakers (who might not read novels, without L&A majors, didn't go to university etc.)? would it be possible that certain number of Americans cannot achieve similar rate as yours? for example, do you think some friend of yours without college degree could know most of these words like you?

@Lambie for my native language Chinese, when we first encountered the Chinese words corresponding to the above list, we would immediately know the meaning because they are structured in a way that you can easily infer the meaning from the ingredients of the word, the ingredients come from a very limited set of characters. Yes, we just DO NOT NEED TO READ IT FIRST TO know the meaning.

@CynthiaZ Words don't have ingredients that allow inference. Of course, a person might hear any of those words in many different places. But YOU asked about those terms and The Tale of Two Cities and how native speakers learn this type of thing. I took the time to share with you my experience and reading. What you say about Chinese seems very unlikely. You know every literary word because there are limited characters in Chinese? Hmm.

@Lambie most of Chinese words are structured in a more scientific way (also due to its later development on these modern terms we should admit) Chinese DO HAVE INGREIDENTS to infer because a word might be constituted of several characters, and even each character share some common sub-parts with others. You cannot make a conclusion on a language you completely don't know.

Ok, Cynthia Z, Linguistics does not accept that words in languages have ingredients. That list in Chinese would require translation which I am completely unqualified to do. Chinese words exist in writing through characters, that are non-syllabic. But regardless, these words are not all common. Why would they be any less common in Chinese, if  properly translated?  Why you are even trying to extend this discussion to Chinese is beyond me. It's irrelevant to your question. I guess high-level of vocabulary in China doesn't come from reading. I wonder where it comes from.

There is no such thing as words being structured in a more scientific way. That is un-linguistic and wrong.
